# Why ChainSaw cannot display logger name?

Tags: log4j, apache-chainsaw

I am using the latest [ChainSaw developer snapshot](http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/)

I'm trying get logs from a file with logs in pattern :

```
[%d] [%t] [%c] [%m]%n
```

and I don't know why it doesn't work - whole log is read as `%m`. When I use pattern without `%c` every log is displayed correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern instead

[TIMESTAMP] [THREAD] [LOGGER] [MESSAGE]

(I'm assuming your logs also have those "[]", otherwise remove them)

Comment: It didn't help, unfortunately. I added some screen shots.

Comment: The viewer does not expect there to be a space in the logger name (Component A), change it to ComponentA and it should hopefully work fine.

Comment: Good bug find - I'll put in a fix for that!